# Is there way to add date difference values we get to the date automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I was trying to do is I have two dates and using `DateDiff` to get a difference between dates. For example, I Have planned `Start Date` and `actual start Date` and I got the difference between this date is `5`, now I want to add this day to the `Finish date`.

If my `Finish date` is not what I assumed, but behind, then that difference we got I want to add and want to find next `finish date` because we are behind so next upcoming dates.

```
Sum (DATEDIFF(day, sa.PlannedStartDate, sa.ActualStartDate)) OVER 
  (Partition 
    By ts.Id)as  TotalVariance,
     Case when (Sum (DATEDIFF(day, sa.PlannedStartDate, sa.ActualStartDate)) 
   OVER 
  (Partition By ts.Id) >30) then 'Positive' end as Violation,
  DATEADD (day, DATEDIFF(day, sa.PlannedStartDate, sa.ActualStartDate))as 
  Summar violations,
```

If the activity **1** - `planned Start date` is `8/21/2019` but the `actual start date` is `9/21/2019`, in this case we are behind 30 days.

Now the next activity will be delayed, so I want to add this difference to the next activity.

If the second activity `planned Start date` was `08/25/2019`, but because of the delay of activity 1 the `start date` will change for second activity, in this case I want to find that new date.

```
  Activity   PlannedStartdate  ActualStartDate  Variance NewPlannedstartdate
  Activity 1  8/21/2019         9/21/2019           30
  Acivity  2  8/26/2019         null                        9/26/2019
```

Comment: How many related activity can be there in the table? Can you add some sample data?

Comment: The broad answer to your question is that you can use the calculation you used to find the difference as the second parameter in `DATEADD`, but without sample data or the code you're using to arrive at your final result, it's difficult to be any more specific in how, exactly, you should go about doing that.

Comment: I would like to know how the data is ordered in the table. You can look into [Lag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to get the date difference of previous row to recalculate `NewPlannedstartdate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example you can run in SSMS:

```
-- CREATE ACTIVITY TABLE AND ADD SOME DATA --
DECLARE @Activity TABLE ( ActivityId INT, PlannedStart DATE, ActualStart DATE );

INSERT INTO @Activity ( 
    ActivityId, PlannedStart, ActualStart 
)
VALUES 
( 1, '08/21/2019', '08/27/2019' ), ( 1, '08/26/2019', NULL ), ( 1, '09/14/2019', NULL );
```

Query @Activity to see what's in it:

```
SELECT * FROM @Activity ORDER BY ActivityId, PlannedStart;
```

@Activity content:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| ActivityId | PlannedStart | ActualStart |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
|          1 | 2019-08-21   | 2019-08-27  |
|          1 | 2019-08-26   | NULL        |
|          1 | 2019-09-14   | NULL        |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Query @Activity to factor the new starting dates:

```
;WITH Activity_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY PlannedStart ) AS Id,
        ActivityId, PlannedStart, ActualStart, DATEDIFF( dd, PlannedStart, ActualStart ) Delayed
    FROM @Activity
    WHERE
        ActivityId = @ActivityId
)
SELECT
    ActivityId,
    PlannedStart,
    ActualStart,
    DATEADD( dd, Delays.DaysDelayed, PlannedStart ) AS NewStart
FROM Activity_CTE AS Activity
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN ( Delayed IS NOT NULL ) THEN Delayed
        ELSE ISNULL( ( SELECT TOP 1 Delayed FROM Activity_CTE WHERE Id < Activity.Id AND Delayed IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Id DESC ), 0 )
    END AS DaysDelayed
) AS Delays
ORDER BY
    PlannedStart;
```

Returns

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| ActivityId | PlannedStart | ActualStart |  NewStart  |
+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|          1 | 2019-08-21   | 2019-08-27  | 2019-08-27 |
|          1 | 2019-08-26   | NULL        | 2019-09-01 |
|          1 | 2019-09-14   | NULL        | 2019-09-20 |
+------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

The real "magic" here is this line:

```
ELSE ISNULL( ( SELECT TOP 1 Delayed FROM Activity_CTE WHERE Id < Activity.Id AND Delayed IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Id DESC ), 0 )
```

It's checking for any prior records to itself that has a delay. If none are found, it returns 0. This value is then used to add days to the **PlannedStart** date to determine the **NewStart** date. The ORDER BY is of particular note too. Sorting in a DESC order ensures we get the "closest" delay prior to the current row.

Using a CTE in this way also takes into account the idea that the delay may not happen on the very first record (e.g., say the 08/26 planned was delayed instead of 08/21). It conveniently gives us a subtable to query against in our OUTER APPLY.

This is what you would see if you included all columns on the CTE's SELECT:

```
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| Id | ActivityId | PlannedStart | ActualStart | Delayed | DaysDelayed |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 | 2019-08-21   | 2019-08-27  | 6       |           6 |
|  2 |          1 | 2019-08-26   | NULL        | NULL    |           6 |
|  3 |          1 | 2019-09-14   | NULL        | NULL    |           6 |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

Because the very first record is the only record with a delay, its delay of 6 days persists through each of the following records.

Comment: You are Awesome, Thank you very much. One quick question if the other activity gets delayed it will add up the days and give us the new start date accordingly right?

Comment: Play around with this, changing up the data that's inserted into @Activity and you'll see how it works. However, to (I think) answer your question, if the first activity had a delay and then the second activity had a delay, the third activity's NewStart date will be calculated from the delay of the second, not the first. It's basically a chain reaction based on the previous activity's ActualStart vs PlannedStart. However, playing with the data will be the real test for you. Make no assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much